# How to keep @ character in SWT menu item text

Tags: java, swt, jface

I built a Java application using SWT and JFace (on Windows). Here I would like to put an email address as text in a menu item and use the following action class:

```
private class MyAction extends Action {
    public MyAction() {
        super("xyz@gmail.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to execute
    }
}
```

and of course:

```
protected MenuManager createMenuManager() {
    MenuManager menuBar = new MenuManager();
    MenuManager myMenu = new MenuManager("Menu");
    myMenu.add(new MyAction());
    menuBar.add(myMenu);
    return menuBar;
}
```

What confuses me a bit is that when the menu is displayed, the "at" character is missing and a space is shown in its place instead.

Can I somehow keep the @ character?

I've already tried putting a double backslash in front of the @ character or replacing the @ character with the Unicode notation \u0040 - neither of which helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the "accelerator" text handling in the `Action` code which converts anything following a tab or @ if there is no tab to a separate part of the menu.

Since the code first looks for a tab before it looks for @ using:

```
super("xyz@gmail.com\t");  // Added tab at end
```

seems to work.

You could also use `\uFF20` "large commercial @" or `\uFE6B` "small commercial @" if the font being used supports them.

Alternatively just using `Menu`, `MenuItem` and listeners rather than `MenuManager` also  works.

Comment: I decided to use the TAB at the end. Works fine, thanks!